# How to configure app.yaml for php?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, yaml

My application's directory structure is as follows...

```
/
 /folder1/index.php
 /folder1/page1.php
 /folder1/page2.php
 /folder2/index.php
 /folder2/page1.php
 /folder2/page2.php
```

In the app.yaml I have written the following...

```
application: myAppID
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|GIF|png|PNG|jpg|JPG|ico|ICO|js|JS|css|CSS))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|GIF|png|PNG|jpg|JPG|ico|ICO|js|JS|css|CSS))

- url: /
  script: index.php
```

Except for home page no other page is loading properly !!! I understand the app.yaml needs to be re-written. But do I need to specify each an every folder and script of my application on there is any wildcard way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you read the section on configuring [script handlers](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig#PHP_app_yaml_Script_handlers)?

You can use back references.

```
- url: /(.*)/
  script: \1/index.php

- url: .*
  script: index.php
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes I read the script handlers section but could not derive my URL structure from it, probably because I am not good at YAML wild cards. Now, apart from home page (/) folder roots(/folder1/index.php, /folder2/index.php) are loading properly. But for any other page within the folder (/folder1/page1.php, /folder1/page2.php) home page content is being loaded !!!

Comment: You need to specify a second grouping to map the second part of the URL, as per the page in the documentation I linked above. Something like /(.*)?/(.*)\.php$ and then script: \1/\2.php

Comment: Thanks a LOT. Its working!

But I have a finding. I used to run my PHP [mock test](http://www.cybermocktest.com) site on App Engine for Java using resin.jar for more than a year and I never faced a problem. Recently, as I noticed App Engine has rolled out official support for PHP, I thought of shifting to it and hence temporarily moved the domain to another server. But my experiment is showing a few page that requires multiple trips to the server are failed to load on PHP runtime which loaded perfectly on Java runtime! Now I am confused whether to shift to PHP runtime or stick to Java runtime.